# Deleting photos does not delete them from storage

Tags: photos

I've been sorting my library in photos, and when looking through, pressing delete removes them from my library, but they remain in place on my hard drive. Is there an option I haven't found to delete them altogether easily?

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 4):

No problem - just seen there is a rubbish bin!